# Pass-by-value, overloading or perfect forwarding for class type parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, pass-by-value, perfect-forwarding

Everytime I think about the design of my class I ask myself these questions, should I use the pass by value, should I overload on const lvalue reference and rvalue reference or should I use perfect forwarding.

Often I use pass by value as having cheap to move types and I almost never use perfect forwarding. I overload when having only 1 parameter, maybe 2 if i really need the perf.

What do you do ?

Do you have easy rules of thumb to decide how to pass arguments, for member/non member functions but also for constructors and all the copy/assignment guys.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for a survey of opinions or choices are poor questions for stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

So all of the following is opinion-based, but these are the rules I tend to follow when thinking about an API. As always in C++, there are many ways to accomplish the same thing, and people will have different view on exactly what is best.

There are three kinds of parameters we need to think about: *in* parameters, *out* parameters, and *in/out* parameters. The latter two are simple, so we'll cover them first.

#### Out parameters

Don't use them. Seriously. If your function is going to return a new object, then return it by value. If you're going to return *multiple* new objects, then return them by value packed in a `std::tuple` (or `std::pair`). The caller can use `std::tie` (or structured bindings in C++17) to unpack them again. This gives the caller the maximum flexibility, and with RVO it's no less efficient than any other method.

#### In/out parameters

For functions which modify an already-constructed value, use a mutable lvalue reference, i.e. `T&`. This will prevent callers from passing a temporary, but that's actually a good thing: what would be the point of modifying something you're just going to throw away? Not that some style guides (notably Google's, but also Qt) advocate using a raw pointer (`T*`) in this situation, so that it's obvious at the call site that the argument will be modified (because you need to say `f(&arg)`), but I personally don't find this convincing.

#### In parameters

For pure input parameters, where the function will not modify the argument passed to it, things are a tiny bit more complicated. In general, the best advice is to pass by lvalue-reference-to-`const`, that is, `const T&`. This will allow the caller to pass both lvalues and rvalues. However, for small objects (`sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)`), such as `int`, it can be more efficient to pass by value instead.

An exception though is if you're going to take a copy of a passed argument, for example in a constructor; in this case, it's better to take the parameter by value, because the compiler can turn this into a move for rvalues.

#### What about T&&?

There are two circumstances where it's appropriate to use arguments of the form `T&&`. The first is templated forwarding functions where the type of the parameter is the template type, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) func(T&& arg) {
    return other_func(std::forward<T>(arg));
}
```

In this case, although the parameter looks as if it's an rvalue reference, it's actually a *forwarding reference* (sometimes called a *universal reference*). Only use a forwarding reference to pass things on to another function via `std::forward`; if you care about the value category of the argument, then `T&&` is not appropriate.

The second case is for real rvalue references, where the argument type is not a template parameter. In a very limited number of cases, it can be appropriate to overload on both the `const arg&` and `arg&&` forms, to avoid an unnecessary move. This should only be necessary in performance-critical situations in which you're going to copy or move the argument somewhere (for example, `std::vector` does this for its `push_back()` method) -- in general I would say it's better to take the argument by value and then move it into place.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces should express intent.

Optimisations should happen when users complain.

To me, the following interfaces have different meanings:

```
void foo(thing const& t); // "I won't modify your t. If it's copyable, I might copy it, but that's none of your concern."

void foo(thing t); // "Pass me a copy if you wish, or a temporary, or move your thing into me. What I do with t is up to me".

void foo(thing& t);  // "t will be modified."
```

Answer (score 1):

*What follows now is only for "default" behavior. Like "normal" not really big types ("normal sized" vectors, strings etc.) nothing which seems to be very expensive in the first place.*

In short: 
**Do whatever you like but be consistent.** 
There is no best practice which can guarantee you the best performance.

Some detail to this:

I was once on a conference having 3 popular C++ people (Herb Sutter, Andrei Alexandrescu and Scott Meyers) discuss this problem and each had another opinion on the best "default" behavior.

All by const-reference or by perfect-forwarding or just by-value.

So you won't get a perfect answer here. Compilers also can optimize differently etc.

**Here is my personal opinion on this:**

What I do is I prefer the by-value approach and if I later notice some thing becoming slow I start to optimize. I assume modern compilers being smart enough to avoid unnecessary copies and also maybe just move the object when they see it's no longer used afterwards. I try to keep in mind [Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) to let the compiler more easier optimize here if necessary (either return only one object or only r-values).

Though I have heard this behavior and optimization potential changing from compiler to compiler. So like said before: use what you prefer / stick to one way so it's consistent.